# I want to put 0 instead of negative values from DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, postgresql

The table with the following structure is considered:

MEDICINE: (name, price, quantity, expiration_date );

I did

```
SELECT Name,
DATEDIFF(expiration_date, CURRENT_DATE) 
AS days
FROM MEDICINE;
```

I got negative results from datediff, but I want to put 0 instead of the negative values. How can I make this? Any help?

Comment: A simple case expression would do the trick

Comment: how to do this ? I am completely begginer in sql

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Is there a `datediff()` function in Postgres? (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: If that query works for you, then you are not using Postgres

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  Name
,       CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(expiration_date, CURRENT_DATE) < 0 THEN 0
            ELSE DATEDIFF(expiration_date, CURRENT_DATE)
        END AS days
FROM MEDICINE;
```

Unfortunately you have to repeat the expression, but the engine should be smart enough to only calculate it once.

Comment: No need to repeat the expression if you chose to use a derived table.

Comment: @jarlh yeah there are several ways to prevent that, but I thought it best to keep it simple, and intuitive, considering Op is apparently a complete beginner

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
GREATEST(0, DATEDIFF(expiration_date, CURRENT_DATE))
```

Read about these conditional operators [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST). Spend some time reading about the suite of functions and operators in your SQL language: it's time well spent.

Comment: Thanks for catching that link error, @FrankHeikens. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GREATEST() in combination with a - because DATEDIFF() doesn't exist in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT Name,
 GREATEST(expiration_date - CURRENT_DATE, 0) 
AS days
FROM MEDICINE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using SQL case.
This should work:

```
SELECT Name,
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(expiration_date, CURRENT_DATE) > 0 THEN DATEDIFF(expiration_date, CURRENT_DATE)
ELSE 0
END
AS days
FROM MEDICINE;
```

You can read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: With respect, w3schools? Really? Friends don't let friends.  Most of their stuff is OK, but the stuff that isn't really isn't